# Select2 edge browser script error on open

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, jquery-select2

I have an application where I am using select2 dropdowns. If I open the dropdown while on the Edge browser I get the following script error:

Could not complete the operation due to error 800a025e.

Select2 also isn't able to calculate the dropdown's top and left property because of it (so the dropdown appears in the top left corner of the screen).

Any sort of help would be apprciated.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Sorry for not responding. It turns out it wasn't my code, I just needed to update my .NET framework to the newest version